# .bat file to move other files based on file name

Tags: batch-file, filenames, move

I have two folders. "Folder one" in which "folder two" is located. In "folder two" are .png files which carry the names of the files I would like to move from "folder one" to "folder two".

Png file name: "Title.EXT.png".

my attempt which is not yet complete

````
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "source_folder=C:\Users\XXX\Folderone"
set "dest_root_folder=C:\Users\XXX\Folderone\Foldertwo"
set "files_per_folder=5000"
set "current_folder=1"
set "file_count=0"

for %%A in ("%source_folder%\*") do (
    move "%%A" "%dest_root_folder%\!current_folder!\%%~nxA" >nul
)```
````

Answer (score 1):

batch processing is quite hard when you are dealing with files with "double" extensions. I would advise you to use `forfiles` for that, as you can see from this simple example:

```
forfiles /C "cmd /c echo file=@file, fname=@fname, ext=@ext, path=@path"
```

This command shows you the interesting `forfiles` variables you might use for your purpose.

Comment: I have looked at the forfiles commando and think it is a good idea. I have not yet figured out exactly how to use it to implement my idea. (unfortunately still a beginner in batch)